# Is it possible to connect additional PTYs to a docker container?

Tags: docker

`docker run` has the `-t` option, which connects the stdin and stdout of the main process to a PTY. But is it possible to somehow define and map additional PTYs?

I am using Docker to simplify setting up a virtualised environment (i.e. running actual init in the container) and would like to use `/lib/systemd/system/container-getty@.service` if possible—of course `systemd` would primarily consider `systemd-nspawn` for the purpose, which is more flexible—but much more work to set up.

Comment: Can the "docker exec" and "docker attach" commands help you? Did you check them?

Comment: This sounds like you want a standard VM; Docker doesn’t really have the concept of “tty” _per se_, and systemd doesn’t run will in a Docker container.